# Does discarding a Race or Class card at "any time" apply to both your hand and cards in play?

Tags: munchkin

In the instructions for Munchkin it says:

"You can discard a Race card at any time, even in combat"
"You can discard a Class card at any time, even in combat"

but it doesn't state whether this applies to your hand, cards in play, or both. Does the rule apply to both?

Also, does this mean that a player may discard these cards during any phase, even when it's not there turn?

Comment: You can find your answer in this question http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8318/

Comment: @MikeR, if you don't have close-vote privileges yet, you can still flag the question to request a close vote.

Comment: @MikeR The question and answer doesn't not address the issue of when this can be done. What does "any time" apply to? Is it any time during a turn or any time during the game? "even in combat" seems to put it in the context of a turn but it's still not completely clear.